# Is there a topological space and meanwhile a linear space such that its vector addition is discontinuous but scalar multiplication is continuous?

Tags: differential-topology, topological-vector-spaces

The title is the question.

Does there exist a topological space and meanwhile a linear space X such that its vector addition operation is discontinuous but scalar multiplication operation is continuous?

I really find it difficult for me. Help me please. I can't work it out so far.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Let $V=\mathbb R^2$ and declare $U\subset V$ open iff for all $v\in U$, $a\in\mathbb R$ also $av\in U$.

Comment: I have known that this is a topology, but what is the open set in this topology? And I know that this topology is not a kolmogorov space(because its single-point set is not closed),but is is first countable or second countable? I cannot prove that its vector addition operation is discontinuous? Help me please.

Comment: I think it's wrong, because it looks like its vector addition is discontinuous and scalar multiplication is discontinuous too. Do you think?